# Maximum load resistor for a given single transistor circuit

Tags: transistors, bjt, pnp

[image]

Following parameters are given for the above circuit:

R1=8.2 kΩ, R2=5.6kΩ, RE=2.7kΩ, VEB=Uj=0.7V, Vcc=10V, β=200

The question asks the maximum load resistance RL for the transistor in active mode.

I solve the question in the following way:

[image]

The maximum load resistance RL for the transistor in active mode means to me the transistor is approaching to saturation at that point.

So for that point, I take Vce=0 and set Vy=Vx+0.7V.

Since Vx=Vcc*R2/(R1+R2)

Vy=Vcc*R2/(R1+R2) + 0.7V

Vy=10*(5.6/13.8) + 0.7V = 4.76V

Now since Vce=0V, and Ie=(Vcc-Vy)/Re = 1.94mA

Ic = Ie approximately so

RL = Vy/Ic = 4.76V/1.94mA = 2.45kΩ

So I calculate the maximum RL in active region as 2.45kΩ, whereas the answer is 2.1kΩ.

Is my calculation wrong?

Comment: Active mode =/= saturation; you will have some voltage drop from collector to emitter.

Comment: Vce=0 means the transistor is in hard saturation. Vce> 200 mV is more realistic. Solution likely uses Vbc =0

Comment: I agree with @sstobbe. The answer uses \$V_{BC}=0\$, which is the same place I use to demark the end of the active region and the start of (very shallow) saturation. (You should get a base current of about \$9.6\:\mu\textrm{A}\$, which I think you do.)

Comment: Vce = Vbc+Vbe vectorially. When Vbc=0 since Vbe is always around 700mV, does that mean the question takes Vce=700mV instead of zero?

Comment: Yes the point where Vce = 700 mV is a good point for separating the active mode and saturation regions.

Answer (score 2):

The following two schematics are equivalent:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fstcDPm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where \$V_{TH}=V_{CC}\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$ and \$R_{TH}=\frac{R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$.

From the above, and assuming \$I_B^{'}=\mid I_B\mid\$ and \$V_{BE}^{'}=\mid V_{BE}\mid\$, you can compute:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{TH}+ I_B^{'}\cdot R_{TH}+ V_{BE}^{'} + I_B^{'}\cdot\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_E&=V_{CC}\\\\
\therefore\quad
I_B^{'}=\frac{V_{CC}-V_{TH}-V_{BE}^{'}}{R_{TH}+\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_E}
\end{align*}$$

Given your values, I get \$I_B^{'}\approx 9.6\:\mu\textrm{A}\$.

The start of shallow entry into saturation occurs right when \$V_{BC}=0\:\textrm{V}\$ or when \$V_B=V_C\$:

$$\begin{align*}
V_C&=V_B\\\\
I_C\cdot R_L &= V_{TH}+I_B^{'}\cdot R_{TH}\\\\
\beta\: I_B^{'}\cdot R_L &=V_{TH}+I_B^{'}\cdot R_{TH}\\\\
\therefore \quad R_L &=\frac{V_{TH}+I_B^{'}\cdot R_{TH}}{\beta\: I_B^{'}}=\frac{1}{\beta}\left(R_{TH}+\frac{V_{TH}}{I_B^{'}}\right)
\end{align*}$$

From which I get \$R_L\approx 2130\:\Omega\$.

Answer (score -4):

Maximum gain for CE stage is VDD/0.026; the current is irrelevant (within reason).

Consider a 26 volt battery. You can operate at 1mA (thus 24Kohm allows 2 volts across the Vce, so bipolar is just barely out of saturation), or 10mA  or 100mA,
or 1uA (with 24,000,000 Ohm Rcollector)

Comment: Yeah. It maxes out at \$40\cdot V_{CC}\$. But I think the OP had a different question. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Indeed, the question was a very different one.

Comment: Then I apologize for providing insight to the OP.